# Rails Active Admin Add Pagination to Top of Index Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Active Admin in Rails defaults to putting pagination on the bottom of index pages. How can I customize the index pages to add it to the top of the page as well? (Would be helpful to right away see how many records/pages you're dealing with instead of first needing to scroll all the way down...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Figured it out. To add pagination to an individual index page I added within the index block (in the admin file) above the table info:

```
paginated_collection(collection, download_links: false)
```

That duplicated the pagination bar from the bottom but taking away the download links. I'm sure there's a way to change this globally (add this to the index template) but I couldn't figure that out.

Example:

```
index do

  div class: 'top_pagination' do
    paginated_collection(collection, download_links: false)
  end

  column :full_name
  column :email
  actions

end
```

Comment: can you provide an example? I tried adding it in the ```index ....``` block, but it failed. I'm on Version 1.0.0.pre2